Discussions can have more than 5 tags
It looked like someone was experimenting/playing with Discussions last night, and they were able to have a post (post is now deleted so mod-link only) that had 10 tags in total.

It appeared they were only able to achieve this with an edit, as the post only had a few tags initially (one tag that was also new and incredibly long in length).

Also "are-tag-names-validated-here-or-not-oh-i-guess-not-thats-kind-of-funny-but-sort-of-makes-sense-i-suppose" mod-only link: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/79216741/1

I don't know what the maximum length for a tag on Main is, @M-- , but if that brakes it, I would suggest that is raised as a separate issue. SEDE implies the maximum length is 35 characters though (dbo.Tags.TagName is defined as an nvarchar(35)) so does seem like a [[meta-tag:bug]] as well.
